# How to keep the page paginated using django-filters when no filter is applied?

Tags: python, django, django-filters

I'm using django-filters to filter categories and price. My problem is that, when I'm filtering results, it's paginated, but when there are no filters applied, there is no pagination. How can I add pagination when there are no filters applied? Thanks in advance!

My filters.py:

```
import django_filters
from .models import Item

class ItemFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):

    class Meta:
        model = Item

        fields = {
            'category': ['exact'],
            'price': ['lte']
        }
```

My views.py:

```
class homeview(ListView):
    model = Item
    template_name = 'products/home.html'
    paginate_by = 8

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['filter'] = ItemFilter(self.request.GET, queryset=self.get_queryset())
        return context
```

My home.html:

```
<div class="card">
          <div class="card-body">
            <div class="container">
              <form method="GET">
                {{ filter.form|crispy }}
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-4">Filter</button>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <h1 class="mb-4">List Of Items</h1>
        <div class="row">
          {% for item in filter.qs %}
           ....
          {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

````
class ListModelMixin:
    """
    List a queryset.
    """
    def list(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = self.filter_queryset(self.get_queryset())

        page = self.paginate_queryset(queryset)
        if page is not None:
            serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
            return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

        serializer = self.get_serializer(queryset, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)```
````

Comment: Can you please show how should I add it in my case?
That would be helpful